# JetBrains PhpStorm Not Resolving Server Variable?

Tags: php, variables, path, phpstorm, server-variables

The following line...

```
require_once $abs_us_root.$us_url_root.'users/includes/header.php';
```

is producing the IDE error:

> Path '/var/www/projectName$us_url_rootusers/includes/header.php' not found.

the actual path to the file is

> /var/www/projectName/public_html/users/includes/header.php

The variable is defined as:

```
$abs_us_root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

Here are the deployment options I have set...

Type: `Local or mounted folder`

Upload/download project files: `/var/www/projectName`

Web server root URL: `http://projectName`

Local path: `/var/www/projectName/public_html`

Deployment path on server: `/`

Web path on server: `/`

Comment: Thanks chris85 for that formatting. I'll be more mindful of it from now on.

Comment: 1) As you can see from the 1st error IDE cannot resolve the value of `$us_url_root` 2) ATM PhpStorm will **always** resolve `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to the project root. There is no settings where you can specify such path .. so IDE devs have created a default rule -- this variable will be resolved to the project root folder (see it here:  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-3321#comment=27-890003). 3) Deployment settings are not taken into consideration (plus, there is no special settings that would explicitly say -- this folder is a web server root).

Comment: 4) Your `$us_url_root` is calculated dynamically during runtime (based on your [WI-34073](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-34073) ticket) -- ATM IDE does not care about dynamic variable values.

Comment: @LazyOne I've had to create a commented out line ($us_url_root = "/public_html";) to uncomment and use for debugging. If you'd like to put your comment in the form of an answer with perhaps my workaround as well I'll accept it.